# data-src tags working in index.html, but not working in angular views

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am relatively new to angular and to javascript, so please accept my apologies if I sound stupid.

I am trying to incorporate a theme to angular. I have noticed that if I include the whole code to index.html, the website works, but when I shift the code to controllers and call them via `<div ui-view></div>`, the rendered page misses some key components.

For e.g. the following causes a header background video to be played:

```
<img src="img/video_fix.png" alt="" class="header-video--media" data-video-src="video/intro" data-teaser-source="video/intro" data-provider="Vimeo" data-video-width="1920" data-video-height="960">
```

If I include it in index.html, it works fine. But if I include it in a controller, it does not render.

Another code that does not render:

```
<section class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/bg_office.jpg" data-natural-width="1200" data-natural-height="600">
```

Upon searching, I came to know that you cannot include jQuery plugins directly in views, but must do so in directives. However, I have not been able to find any guide that may enable me to understand how to incorporate jQuery plugins in angular views.

The following code is included in index.html:

```
<script src="js/video_header.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    HeaderVideo.init({
      container: $('.header-video'),
      header: $('.header-video--media'),
      videoTrigger: $("#video-trigger"),
      autoPlayVideo: true
    });

  });
</script>
```

Here is the code for video_header.js

```
var HeaderVideo = function (e, i) {
  var o = {
    container: e(".header-video"),
    header: e(".header-video--media"),
    videoTrigger: e("#video-trigger"),
    videoCloseTrigger: e("#video-close-trigger"),
    teaserVideo: e("#teaser-video"),
    autoPlayVideo: !1
  }, r = function (i) {
    o = e.extend(o, i), t(), d(), a(), o.videoCloseTrigger.hide(), videoDetails.teaser && n(), o.autoPlayVideo && l()
  }, t = function () {
    return videoDetails = {
      id: o.header.attr("data-video-src"),
      teaser: o.header.attr("data-teaser-source"),
      provider: o.header.attr("data-provider").toLowerCase(),
      videoHeight: o.header.attr("data-video-height"),
      videoWidth: o.header.attr("data-video-width")
    }, videoDetails
  }, d = function () {
    o.container.data("aspectRatio", videoDetails.videoHeight / videoDetails.videoWidth), e(window).resize(function () {
      var i = e(window).width(), r = e(window).height();
      o.container.width(i).height(i * o.container.data("aspectRatio")), r < o.container.height() && o.container.width(i).height(r)
    }).trigger("resize")
  }, a = function () {
    o.videoTrigger.on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault(), l(), o.videoCloseTrigger.fadeIn()
    }), o.videoCloseTrigger.on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault(), s()
    })
  }, n = function () {
    if (Modernizr.video && !f()) {
      var e = videoDetails.teaser, i = '<video autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted id="teaser-video" class="teaser-video"><source src="' + e + '.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="' + e + '.ogv" type="video/ogg"></video>';
      o.container.append(i)
    }
  }, v = function () {
    if ("youtube" === videoDetails.provider)var e = '<iframe id="video" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoDetails.id + '?rel=0&amp;hd=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=*" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>'; else if ("vimeo" === videoDetails.provider)var e = '<iframe id="video" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/' + videoDetails.id + '?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=3d96d2&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>'; else if ("html5" === videoDetails.provider)var e = '<video autoplay="true" loop="loop" id="video"><source src="' + videoDetails.id + '.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="' + videoDetails.id + '.ogv" type="video/ogg"></video>';
    return e
  }, l = function () {
    o.header.hide(), o.container.append(v()), c(), o.teaserVideo.hide()
  }, s = function () {
    e("#video").remove(), o.teaserVideo.fadeIn(), u(), g()
  }, c = function () {
    o.videoTrigger && o.videoTrigger.fadeOut("slow")
  }, u = function () {
    o.videoTrigger && o.videoTrigger.fadeIn("slow")
  }, g = function () {
    o.videoCloseTrigger.hide()
  }, f = function () {
    return e(window).width() < 900 && Modernizr.touch ? !0 : !1
  };
  return {init: r}
}(jQuery, document);
```

Comment: Make sure you are not using jquery outside controller that will not work.

Comment: Yes, I have included ng-controller in the body tag. Everything is working except the data-src tags

Comment: Dhould I include jquery in controller?

Comment: Yes otherwise jquery will not work

Comment: Can you share your controller and Html where you are using controller? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Move your jquery code into controller. Using jquery separately outside angular will not work. And also make sure jquery is loaded before angular. It's not good practice to mix jquery with angular then angular can do pretty much everything and come with inbuilt lite jquery.